# Dynamic json deserlization Salesforce

Tags: rest-api

I have a requirement in which I will get json with different attributes. Can you please help me to decode the same.

Example 1
{
   "Order_Type": "X",
   {
    Attribute1:"test atr1,
    Attribute2:"test atr2
   }

Example 2

```
{
Order_Type:"prd2",
```

{
    Attr1:"test at1,
    Attr2:"test at2,
    Attr3:"test at3
    }
}

The number of attributes and attribute name will differ for each json based on the product.

Comment: Do you have control over this end point? This is a pretty silly problem that you shouldn't have to deal with, but I think you may be able to use https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_jsongenerator.htm

Comment: No I don't have. The above is the response I will get from the external system. With this I should be able to insert product configuration in Salesforce.

Comment: The posted JSON examples are not valid JSON objects. You will not be able to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pretty standard way to handle this is to deserialize into a map and then look at the keys you've got:

```
Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);

String orderType = m.get('Order type');
if (orderType == 'Product 1') {
    // Handle keys like "Attribute1"
} else if (orderType == 'prd2') {
    // Handle keys like "Attr1"
}
```

or you can e.g. support two different names:

```
String a1 = m.get('Attribute1');
if (a1 == null) a1 = m.get('Attr1');
```

or you can iterate over the keys and add whatever logic works:

```
for (String key : m.keySet()) {
    String value = m.get(key);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but here I would have almost 100 products.. and each product can have up to 50 (it can even be more in future) attributes.

Comment: @bksfdc Then you should think about various design patterns that might let you write reasonably clean code e.g. you might end up with a separate class per product or a data structure per product. But the point is the platform lets you do that - the hard work is your problem. (You don't explain what you need to do; one option is to just store the JSON in its raw format.)

Answer (score 1):

For Dynamic JSON deserialization ,you will need to Deserialize using [deserialize Untyped](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_Json_deserializeUntyped.htm) .

```
Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonInput);

  for(String s:m.keyset()){
   String attribute=(decimal)m2.get(s);
   //You will get all values here
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but here I would have almost 100 products.. and each product can have up to 50 attributes

Comment: The logic still should work .The keyset of map will get you all the attributes